# Display the str or unicode of an objet on deletion of one of its ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have declared in Django admin.py an `oeuvre` class with a `types` ManyToManyField to an `TypeOeuvre` class.

```
class Oeuvre(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=510)
    types = models.ManyToManyField('TypeOeuvre',
                                   blank=True,
                                   verbose_name="Type(s) de l'œuvre")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['titre']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} [{1}]".format(self.titre[:200], self.id)

class TypeOeuvre(models.Model):
    intitule = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Intitulé')
    commentaire = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                   verbose_name='Commentaire',
                                   blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['intitule']
        verbose_name = "Type d'œuvre"
        verbose_name_plural = "Types d'œuvres"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.intitule
```

However, when I try to delete a TypeOeuvre object in Django Admin for which relations to one *oeuvre* exists, the "Are you sure?" warnings do not explicitly mention the name of the *oeuvre*:

Oeuvre-typeoeuvre relationship: Oeuvre_types object

[image: Are you sure]

Is there a way to display the name of the oeuvres linked to the type ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using python 3 by any chance?

Comment: Like @e4c5 already mentioned, if you are on Python 3 you need to use `def __str__(self)` instead of `def __unicode__(self)` for the object representation.

Comment: no, I am using Python 2.7.11, thanks

Comment: For information, the problem is not solved with Django 1.10 and Python 3.4.5 + using `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`...